# Disabling GCC auto-parallelisation

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm running MinGW G++ 4.8.1, and when I changed the following code:

```
for (Room &r : TempRooms2) {  
    r.vNeighbours.clear();  
}
```

to

```
for (Room &r : TempRooms2) {
    r.vNeighbours.clear();  
    r.Layer=-1;  
}
```

The program, which previously ran perfectly, crashes with a segfault in libwinpthread-1.dll. Now, I hadn't used the threading features of this G++ 4.8.1 build previously, and after testing them it turns out that they're not stable on my OS, so I'll need to change to a different build in future when I want to utilise threading. Until then, is there a way I can tell G++ to stop trying to parallelise loops?

*Edit: Sorry, turns out the crash was due to the code getting into an infinite loop somewhere else. I just assumed it was a threading thing because GDP said a call to 'pthread_tls_init' was segfaulting and I thought only a threaded program would use that. I'd be grateful if anybody could explain why Windows killing the program due to an infinite loop appeared to the debugger as a segfault in pthread.*

Comment: What makes you think your loop is being run in multiple threads? (A segfault in pthread isn't evidence of that.)

Comment: And independent of that, a segmentation fault is not to be treated by changing the compiler or compiler options unless you are sure it isn't just your code or you are explicitly using experimental features. It might by that the bug is just exposed by a specific flag or compiler, in that case you should be thankful for the segfault ...

Comment: @filmor Well the compiler seems to fail when I test it with c++11 threaded code. The following for instance crashes with a segfault in libwinpthread, and I'm pretty sure the code is correct. (TestReturn is a simple function that just returns 1). 
auto f1 = async(launch::async,TestReturn);
int res = f1.get();
So changing the compiler seems like the only option (probably to a build using native windows threads).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC doesn't enable auto-parallelisation unless you request it with e.g. `-ftree-parallelize-loops`

So if you're not using that, then the problem isn't due to auto-parallelisation.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just saw pthread and blindly assumed that it implied threading.